# Finding the area where several circles intersect and the center point of the intersection

Tags: math, gps, geometry

[image]

I have 3 signal receivers indoors, A, B, C, to detect whether customers are standing in the orange highlighted area shown above.

- A: Detected 7 Meters away from A POINT and the X, Y coordinate is 12,10
- B: Detected 5 Meters away from B POINT and the X, Y coordinate is 5,6
- C: Detected 3 Meters away from C POINT and the X, Y coordinate is 8,3

So, now we only got 3 circles, if we had more points the area would be more accurate.

Question: How to find the Highlighted Area Coordinate in the image above, and find the center point of that area (green point in picture). Actually I'm using VB.NET, what math formula I should use?

Comment: You're looking for algorithms for *trilateration*.  These are extensively documented and your search engine will overwhelm you with useful resources.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark Trilateration only for 3 circle? how mabout i got 4 circle? also can use this algorithms?

Comment: Are you sure that is the right formulation of the problem?  You'd want the center point of the marked area if the data was *at most* 7 meters from A, *at most* 5 meters from B and *at most* 3 meters from C.  If the distances as measured are not upper bounds but rather regular estimates,  you're indeed better off with trilateration.

Answer (score 0):

I often find that getting exact geometrically precise answer may result in too much effort. Therefore I would suggest to sample all area with a grid of given step (say 10 cm). For each coordinate check if it is in all circles if yes put that position to list. Finally get average position from list.

Pseudocode:

```
left = min(A.x-A.r, B.x-B.r, C.x-C.r);
top = min(A.y-A.r, B.y-B.r, C.y-C.r);
right = max(A.x+A.r, B.x+B.r, C.x+C.r);
bottom = max(A.y+A.r, B.y+B.r, C.y+C.r);

for (x=left; x<=right; x+=0.1)
    for (y=top; y<=bottom; y+=0.1)
        if (A.inCircle(x,y) && B.inCircle(x,y) && C.inCircle(x,y)) list.add([x,y]);      

return list.getAveragePos();
```

Please note that you can greatly speed this up only by considering grid for the smallest circle.

Comment: can explain what is A.r ? explain all definition. thanks !

Comment: A.x, A.y are circle centre coordinates, A.r is radius. inCircle() checks if point is being in circle (just see if the distance from center is smaller/equal than it's radius)

There's also one more approach, that may have smaller number of points being processed. Instead of processing whole area, you could only check points that are laying on circles perimeters.